# I need help grouping links under one title

Tags: views, blocks

So this is how my webpage looks at the moment.

[image]

However, I need to group each of these links under a certain title. 
The titles are the following (bolded): 
[image]

How do I get each of those links, for ex "Bon Appetit", "Brubakers" to be under the title "Eateries" and so on. How do I create the Group titles?
I just want to know how to get started on it. Do I have to do some coding? (I have no experience on this, by the way.)

Comment: Are all these titles in the first image nodes ?

Comment: Basically if you click on each title from the first image, it goes to the matching title down below on the same page. So if you click on "Bon Appetit" it take you to the "Bon Appetit" below all the titles (and the logo and information displayed under Bon Appetit). It's a long list of services, each title has its own logo/info underneath at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that each of these items are nodes, that have a field referring to the group they're a part of. In your view settings, look for 'FORMAT'. I'm guessing you're using an unformatted list. If you click 'Settings' next to that you should see a 'Grouping Field Nr.1' dropdown box. There you can choose what field to group all the items by and it will automatically group your results with the group title at the top. You have to make sure that you have the group field listed in fields section first.

Comment: When I looked in view settings it said "HTML list" and didn't have a grouping field. Does it have to be unformatted?

Comment: Try unformatted list and see if you get that option. You can always style it exactly the way you want with css.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use [views accordion](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_accordion)

From the module page:

> Views Accordion provides a display style plugin for the Views module.
>   It will take the results and display them as a JQuery accordion, using
>   the first field as the header for the accordion rows.

After installing the module, create a view with format style: **accordion** and adjust its settings.

2) You can do it without extra module by going to your view and under the **format settings** link, you will find selectbox field called: 
**Grouping field Nbr.1**

Note that the views format should be ***Unformatted list***